# Upon the plugging of an usb headphone the audio of an embedded video is automatically unmuted

Tags: audio, usb, html5-video, headphones

```
<html>
<video src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" muted="muted" height="453" width="690"> Your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video>
</html>
```

Try the above code:the video will start automatically muted in a loop.
If you plug some usb headphones the audio will get unmuted.

Why is this happening ?